# SAS proc SQL programming left join and duplications

Tags: sql-server, join, sas

I am trying to join 20 different tables (one table for each month) that have the next columns, all the tables have the same columns:

```
Date|ID_contract|product type|Area|Balance
```

After using the left join of sql (I want to see the evolution of the balance of each contract) I have seen that some products are duplicated. 
The reason of having duplicate contracts is that for some dates, in some tables, the same product appears more than once. For example, in table a27022017:

```
-   Date         ID_contract        Product type      Area      Balance
- 27/02/2017      F123                dividend       Spain        4.587
- 27/02/2017      F123                dividend       Spain       -1.267
- 27/02/2017      F123                dividend       Spain        1.267
```

So, before joining the tables I want to sum the balance of each contract to have only one ID_contract and not to obtain duplications. How can I do it? I am sorry but I am new with SAS.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide sample data

Comment: in SQL you could use a `group by`, but in SAS, I'm not sure.

Comment: Are your datasets already sorted? If so by what variables?

Comment: The datasets are sorted by id_contract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the SUM operator of SQL:

```
SELECT Date, ID_contract, [Product type], Area, SUM(Balance) FROM      
GROUP BY Date, ID_contract, [Product type], Area
```